# ZF3 Doctrine via CLI - missing cli-config.php file

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

I use ZF3 with Doctrine and when I execute the command`./vendor/bin/doctrine` 
to see the possible commands I get this as an error:

> You are missing a "cli-config.php" or "config/cli-config.php" file in your
>   project, which is required to get the Doctrine Console working. You can use the
>   following sample as a template:
>
> ```
> <?php
> use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;
>
> // replace with file to your own project bootstrap
> require_once 'bootstrap.php';
>
> // replace with mechanism to retrieve EntityManager in your app
> $entityManager = GetEntityManager();
>
> return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
> ```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: "I have almost the same problem" 
same as... ?
Please detail your problem

Comment: Did you read the error you get?

Comment: Soooo... ? ....

Comment: Thanks everyone ! my problem is now resolve `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module` instead.

The command you're using is for when you're not using Doctrine as a ZF3 **MODULE**, but as say, a tool in your plain PHP project.

Same as you would use `php bin/console doctrine:*` with Symfony.

[Documentation here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/cli.md)